# 'Microsoft.CSharp.dll' and 'System.Dynamic.dll' not getting added to .net 3.5 solution

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am using .NET 3.5 and FacebookSDK_V4.2.1. I am not able to add references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll' and 'System.Dynamic.dll' to my solution. How can I add these dll's to .NET 3.5 solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Dynamic.dll` is part of .NET 4, to start with... you may be able to install the [Dynamic Language Runtime](http://dlr.codeplex.com/) version for .NET 3.5, but you certainly won't be able to use the `dynamic` feature from C# 4.

I haven't used the Facebook SDK myself, but it sounds like you *either* need a version which targets .NET 3.5 instead of .NET 4, or you need to use .NET 4 for your application.

Comment: is there is anyway to use facebook sdk with .NET 3.5. Nuget also supporting only .NET 4

Comment: @harry: If it's all centred around dynamic typing, then no. I can't see anything on the download site that suggests there's a .NET 3.5 version available.

Comment: facebook c# sdk is only distributed via nuget. if you are using older version of vs that does not support nuget package manager, download the nuget.exe console, and run nuget install facebook, you can then reference facebook.dll from the net35-client folder.

Comment: @prabir: Presumably the way of *using* the .NET 3.5 client is different to the tutorial though, given that it can't use `dynamic`...

Comment: cast json objects (key-value pair) to IDictionary<string,object> arrays to IList<object>, you can then cast primitive types to bool, long, double, string and so on